# Is it possible to bind exchanges of different types together in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

I am currently sending messages to a `Topic` exchange, in which messages are copied to queues based on a matching routing key. I want to be able to copy some of these messages to other consumers based on message headers. Is it possible to achieve this by binding a `Headers` exchange to the `Topic` exchange and then binding queues to that based on the incoming message headers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use an exchange-to-exchange binding [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/e2e.html).